# Codeigniter - Javascript - Pass JS variabel from view to external JS file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I am trying to pass JS variabel in CI view file to JS file in `assets/js` folder.

Here is my `viewFile.html` file:

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){

  var someVariable = <?php echo json_encode($from_controller)?>; 

 });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/myJS.js"></script>
</html>
```

and here is my `myJS.js` file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log(window.someVariable);  
});
```

It's should print a JSON format in my console right? But I get an error and my console print `undefined`. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

It should not because you are declaring it with var, if you just say `someVariable = ...` it might.

However, why don't you just do `window.someVarible = ...` ?

Besides, I wouldn't put it inside the ready event because you aren't sure which event will be called first.

Therefore, I would do this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   window.someVariable = <?php echo json_encode($from_controller)?>;
</script>
```